# Add external solution built by conan to cmake project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, conan, sln-file

I'm trying to add a third-party library (let's say rttr) to the Visual Studio solution we generate through CMake.
So I know if I create an editable package through Conan, then build it from source, I can open and edit it through another instance of Visual Studio and every change in it will be applied to the project solution
The question is how to add this editable package to the project solution?
I tried adding with *include_external_msproject* but it doesn't seem to work.
here is how I built it:

```
conan editable add . rttr/0.9.6.15.1@user/thirdparty
cd project\thirdaprty\rttr
conan install .  rttr/0.9.6.15.1@user/thirdparty
conan source . -sf ..\rttr_src
conan build . -bf .  -sf ..\rttr_src
```

This is the part where I try to add in CMake:

```
include_external_msproject(rttr "D:/rttr")
```

Comment: It is not clear the ``cd project\thirdaprty\rttr``, it seems you are already in the ``rttr`` folder, because you just did ``conan editable add .``, so I expect the folder to be that one. Also, I'd recommend dropping the ``-sf`` and ``-bf`` in favor of ``layout()``.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had to add a path to src
`include_external_msproject(rttr "D:/rttr/src/rttr/rttr_core.vcxproj")`

Though I don't think it is a correct way